# Django ModelChoiceField initial value

Tags: python, django

I have a wizardform returning multiple forms and some of them are defined as formsets. While editing with the same form, I have troubles getting the initial values in ModelChoiceField.

It works for other fields but ModelChoiceField. The fields are defined as CharField in Models. Heres What I've done:

views.py

```
FooFormset = modelformset_factory(model=Foo, form=FooForm, max_num=10,  extra=0,)  
FORMS = {
     "ba": BarForm,
     "fo": FooFormset,
    }

form = form_class = FORMS[step]

if request.method == 'POST':
    #do some postings
else:
    if step in['fo']:
        form = form_class(queryset = model_form_instances)
```

forms.py

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Foo.objects.all(), required=True)
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your view and form code?

Comment: I dont have much in the form file, however in views.py the `POST` method is irrelevent here. The `model_form_instance` mentioned above  is the model instance of the foo class.